# Save names or strings

Tags: c++

Using CPP on visual studios 2019. If needing more info just comment.

The compiler would ask for a name/string, you would enter it then
it would ask again.

If you were to type the same thing twice, the compiler would say "you typed it twice".

The problem is that I don't know how I should go about saving uppercase and lowercase
words because if you were to just type in the same word with a capital the compiler 
would think its a brand new word.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
string word[100];
int x = 0;

  while (1)
{   
   cout << "Enter word.";
   cin >> word[x];
   x++;
// I don't know how to check if words typed in are the same.
// Thats the question.
}
}
```

Comment: why would compiler ask you anything ?

Comment: Because I would say while (1) { cout << "laskdf;ad"; cin >> word;  }

Comment: You have to write the code yourself. This isn't a "write it for me" site. Show the code and go into detail about how you tried to resolve the problem.

Comment: Just to clarify some terminology: the compiler is not asking you anything, the compiler only compiles your program and is not relevant at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering two strings entered in different case as the same string, then you could store the inputted string by transforming it into lower/upper case and then check with the previous value and currently inputted value every time.

Considering you read into `string s`, you could store the string into lower/upper case by using [`std::transform()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/) function.

```
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), ::toupper);
```

Remember to convert the read input into lower/upper case as well before checking both the strings. I gave you the basic idea of how your program would work. Now, write the code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with [std::toupper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper).

Steps:

- input word, save in `std::string`
- input next word
- check words: call

```
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), other.begin(), ::toupper);
```

for both words and if they are the same print first word

Answer (score 0):

You can convert all of the entered word characters into a single case (lower case/upper case), then check if the result is present in the entered words set.

A complete example:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::set<std::string> words{};

    while (true) {
        std::string word{};

        std::cout << "Enter a word: " << std::flush;
        std::cin >> word;

        // Convert word to lower case by adding 32 to each upper case
        // character
        for (auto &c : word) {
            c |= 0x20;
        }

        if (words.count(word)) {
            std::cerr << "You typed `" << word << "' twice!" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        words.emplace(std::move(word));
    }

    return 0;
}
```